# Error in svyciprop using logit or likelihood method

Tags: r, statistics, survey, confidence-interval, proportions

I'm working on an analysis of survey-weighted data from a stratified random sample using the survey library. I have my survey design object:

```
wsvy <- svydesign(ids=df$psu, strata=df$strata, weights=df$pweight, fpc=df$N, data=df)
```

and am estimating a proportion using svyciprop, as such:

```
prop <- svyciprop(~I(y==1), wsvy, method=CI_METHOD, level=0.95)
```

When I use any of these methods -- "beta", "xlogit", "asin", or "mean" -- everything is fine and I get results. However, if I instead use "logit" or "likelihood", I get the following error:

```
Error in svyglm.survey.design(I(y==1) ~ 1, design, family = quasibinomial) : all variables must be in design= argument
```

I've looked around and have found similar questions, but none that have addressed this particular issue, or that have helped me resolve it. I have tried rewriting my survey object this way:

```
wsvy <- svydesign(ids=~psu, strata=~strata, weights==~pweight, fpc=~N, data=df)
```

to no avail. I am currently using the "beta" method, but because Clopper-Pearson is so conservative I would prefer to use one of these other methods (honestly, I'd prefer to use Agresti-Coull or Wilson but these are not included in the svyciprop package).

Does anyone know what's going wrong here? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried putting `y==1` (probably better as numeric instead of boolean) as a variable on the input data rather than create it through the formula? Looks like this might be due to the code trying to match arguments.

Comment: I can't reproduce this error. I assume you've checked that `y` is actually in the `design` object.

Comment: Thank you both, this was indeed the issue. I am computing confidence intervals on several separate outcomes in a loop, and was using y = get(outcome_name), which was apparently throwing off the GLM; I have fixed this by pre-specifying the formula and giving it to svyciprop.

Comment: @ThomasLumley thank you also for the excellent survey package, I have been using it successfully and without any hiccups for some time. I am not a guru though, and have been unable to find an answer online, but do you know if there a reason Wilson/Agresti-Coull intervals do not seem to be used in analyses of complex survey samples? It looks like even SAS does not have Agresti-Coull. Thank you again!

Comment: All the more-accurate ways to get confidence intervals under iid sampling depend on the known mean-variance relationship for binary data, but that relationship need not hold under complex sampling. For the Wilson method, you'd need to work out how to re-estimate the design effect as the parameter changes. I don't know if it performs badly or whether it's just no-one has tried

Comment: On the coding side, you want `bquote` or the tidyverse equivalent to substitute variable names into a formula.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful responses! That makes sense.